# Asynchronously load an XML file

Tags: xml, vb.net, asynchronous

I use this function to reverse geocoding using Google Maps and load an XML with the results:

```
Private Function ReverseGeocode(ByVal Latitud As Double, ByVal Longitud As Double) As String

    Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
    Dim sURL As String = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=@lat,@long&sensor=false"
    sURL = sURL.Replace("@lat", Latitud)
    sURL = sURL.Replace("@long", Longitud)

    Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString(sURL)
    Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument()
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(result)

    Dim m_nodelist As XmlNodeList
    m_nodelist = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/GeocodeResponse/result/formatted_address")
    ReverseGeocode = m_nodelist(0).InnerText
End Function
```

My question: can this be done using an asynchronous method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use an async version of `DownloadString` together with `async` and `await`. You might need to use `Task.Run` to move long-running computations off the UI-thread (in case you have one).